# How to customize Sales Order form with SuiteScript 2.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I didn't find any documentation on advanced customization.

I need to customize Sales Order in a more advanced way than basic customization offered in UI Customization Menu.

For example, add some sublists under Item section with a relation one to many between Item and Messages (1), or add a new button to display a new page to create a messages record page linked with the selected item (2).

Thank you!

[Explicative Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUbGt.png)

Answer (score 0):

NetSuite's current API does not accommodate the use of custom buttons inside sublists (unless you are using the native REFRESH or MARKALL button within a custom Suitelet).

An alternative solution to bridge the gap between the item record and the message record you want to create, why not do the following:

1. First, create a SUITELET which opens as a CHILD window of the current window on FIELDCHANGE of the item.
2. Second, add a basic TEXTAREA field and include the SUBMIT button to the suitelet.
3. On SUBMIT of the Suitelet, ccreate a new message record, attaching it to the current sales order.
4. Lastly - ensure the Suitelet closes itself.

Note: This solution will only work on EDIT of a sales order. It will not work on CREATE because no order ID would exist at the time you submit a message. (You need the order ID to attach the message to).

I hope this suggestion is clear.

Comment: Thank you Arif WB, it's very clear, to open the suitelet, I would prefer to have a custom column with a link that the user clicks when he needs to add the messages, but i can't figurate how.

Comment: Hi Simon - what exactly should happen when the user clicks the link on the custom column?

Comment: Hi @Arif , it will open a Suitelet with SalesOrder Id and Item Id in parameters to add Custom Record instances with parameters as Foreign Key (to be able to load data once is inserted for next click). The Suitelet will contain multiple fields linked with the Custom Record, thank you.

Comment: Hi @Arif , do you have a solution to add a link for each row of items with the selected row id in parameter? I tried to do it with INLINEHTML type but this type is not supported for sublist field. Using the TEXT type renders text and not HTML because the content is surrounded with double quote. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do your customization on BeforeLoad in a UserEvent script : you can access the current form from the context and do somethings like adding buttons, sublists, hiding fields...

You can not add a button, but you can add a link pointing to a Suitelet where you can execute your actions. As an example, I created a sublist with a View link that points out to the line's custom record:

To define the field:

```
var idField = appStepsSublist.addField({
            id: 'id',
            type: serverWidget.FieldType.URL,
            label: 'View'
        });
idField.linkText = 'View';
```

To set Value :

```
var viewUrl = url.resolveRecord({
                            recordType: 'customrecord_nab_approval_step',
                            recordId: appStep.id,
                            isEditMode: false
                        });

usedSublist.setSublistValue({
                            id: 'id',
                            line: index,
                            value: viewUrl
                        });
```

In your case, you can use the URL module to get a Suitelet link and append to it the needed data from your current line.

Comment: Thank you B. Assem, but it does not allow to manage an action on a particular line item because we can add a button in the item section but not a button that refers to a line.

Comment: Thank you @B. Assem . Is it possible to create a column (using context.form) on Items Sales Order Matrix with on BeforeLoad in a UserEvent script? Because I feel that we can't manipulate the matrix as we manipulate a Custom Sublist, I don't see how to do a get() for the native matrix.  Using context.newRecord, I tried to modify the value of a Transaction Line Field I created via UI but we can't save a transaction in the BeforeLoad event.

Comment: Sorry I don't know about the Matrix, and I didn't understand the second part of your question.